# How to implement edit in Django using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have a table with **Payments**

```
<table class="table" id="payments">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Comment</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Show</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Destroy</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        {% for payment in payments %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ payment.created_date|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}</td>
                <td>{{ payment.description }}</td>
                <td>{{ payment.comment }}</td>
                <td>{{ payment.amount }}</td>
                <td><a id="{{ payment.pk }}" class="show_payment">Show</a></td>
                <td><a id="{{ payment.pk }}" class="edit_payment">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a id="{{ payment.pk }}" class="destroy_payment">Destroy</a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Each link to **show** have an id of this payment. When I click to this link my form appears with pre-filled data of the appropriate payment but when I click **Submit** it creates a new payment.

```
$(".edit_payment").click(function () {
    var payment_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/payment/'+payment_id+'/edit/',
        type: 'get',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#hide_payment').show();
            $("#payments").after(data);
            $('#hide_payment').click(function(){
                $("#payment_form").remove();
                $('#hide_payment').hide();
            });
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#payment_form').hide();
    $('#hide_payment').hide();
    //$("#submit_payment").click(function() {
    var form = $("#payment_form");
    var options = {
        success: function(data){
            // var new_element = $(data).find('tr:last');
            // $("#payments").append(new_element);
            $('#payment_form').hide();
        },
        clearForm: true
    };
    $('#payment_form').on('submit', function() {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false;
    });
});
```

But I want to edit this payment not to create new.

```
def payment_edit(request, pk):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():

        if request.user.has_perm('tracker.admin') or request.user.has_perm('tracker.manager'):
            payment = get_object_or_404(Payment, pk=pk)

            if request.method == "POST":
                form = PaymentForm(request.POST, instance=payment)

                if form.is_valid():
                    payment = form.save(commit=False)
                    payment.save()
                    return redirect('payment_list')
            else:
                form = PaymentForm(instance=payment)
            return render(request, 'tracker/payment_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

**Payment form**

```
class PaymentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Payment
        fields = ('comment', 'description', 'amount', 'created_date')
```

Comment: Can you put a print statement in your payment_edit method to see if it's even being used?

Comment: I put the print, it's used.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that I use the same PaymentForm and template for creating and updating?

Comment: Can you print the form properties? Does it contain id?

Comment: Added PaymentForm code.

Comment: Thanks. I mean after you create the form from the request and model instance. Can you verify that the id is there? If it has the id, when saved it shouldn't create a new model.

Comment: You mean as a hidden field in html?

Comment: No I just mean in your payment_edit method, when you save the form. If the form has an id, it should edit that record, and not create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to rewrote my template: use url link in form.